# Is it possible to use Google Android studio and eclipse IDE with android sdk installed in same machine

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I Have eclipse IDE with android sdk installed and Google android studio

When i try to install SDK for android studio , following error is displaying

```
> Done loading packages.
Preparing to install archives
Downloading Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 19.0.2
Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\temp
Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.1
Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\temp
Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.2
Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\temp
Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.1
```

[image]

Comment: Don't download sdk again for android studio use the same one sdk is never change just development environment have been changed use same sdk for android studio

Comment: When i check SDK from eclipse, all the API is installed But in google android studio SDK All the API's are not installed

Comment: Wait i am figuring out i don't use android studio because its not still stable yet :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've installed Android Studio for use by all users, which is problematic on Windows -- it requires that you install and do any subsequent updates as an admin user. I'd suggest installing it only for your own user instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running the latest build (0.8.1) and haven't had that issue.
However, when I was running a build from around the time of this question (0.6.1) I ended up having to go to the SDK dir (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk) and right click the SDK Manager and click 'Run as administrator' and it would run fine.
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you installed "all users" as Scott Barta says, you may try to start Android Developer Studio in "Run as administrator" mode.